# Finding the complement of a regular expression (a|b)*ab(a|b)*

Tags: regex

There's a question on my exercise sheet to find the complement of `r = (a|b)*ab(a|b)*`

I've come up with a solution, but I'm not sure if it's correct. Please help me to check, and correct my errors.

Comment: regarding the last line, I meant L(~r) = L(b*|b*aa*), thus ~r = b*|b*aa*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that `a` and `b` are the only allowed symbols.

Your original expression matches any string that contains `ab`. The complement is any string that does not contain `ab`. In other words if there is an `a` the next character must be another `a` or the end of the string. If a `b` occurs it must be before all `a`s.

So that gives the result:

```
b*a*
```

I think your expression is equivalent to this.

Answer (score 1):

The given RE states the language having substring ab at least once
The complement of the same would be ..language accepting no substring ab

Hence b*a* is the correct answer